# Installation of Qt Messaging framework in mac?

Tags: qt, macos

Can some one explain the steps that are needed to include Messaging framework in to a Qt Application?

I have downloaded the Open source Project that contains the Messaging framework from this link:
http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/solutions/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.1.0-beta2.tar.gz

**UPDATE:**

Raised a bug with Nokia. 
http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTSDK-229

> Running build steps for project
>   writemessage... Configuration
>   unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>   Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -w  make:
>   Entering directory
>   `/Users/xxxxxxx/Qt/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.1.0-beta2/examples/writemessage-build-simulator'
>   g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64
>   -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -arch ppc -arch i386 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_PRINTER -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../../NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/mkspecs/macx-g++
>   -I../writemessage -I../../../../NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers
>   -I../../../../NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/include/QtCore
>   -I../../../../NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers
>   -I../../../../NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/include/QtGui
>   -I../../../../NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/include
>   -I/Users/xxxxxxx/NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/include/QtMessaging
>   -I/Users/xxxxxxx/NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/include/QtMobilitySimulator
>   -I../../src/global -I../../src/messaging -I/Users/xxxxxxx/install/include -I/Users/xxxxxxx/install/include/QtMobility
>   -I/Users/xxxxxxx/install/include/QtMessaging
>   -I../../../../Build/Debug/writemessage/moc
>   -I. -F/Users/xxxxxxx/NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib
>   -o ../../../../Build/Debug/writemessage/messagesender.o
>   ../writemessage/messagesender.cpp  g++
>   -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -arch ppc -arch i386 -o writemessage.app/Contents/MacOS/writemessage
>   ../../../../Build/Debug/writemessage/messagesender.o
>   ../../../../Build/Debug/writemessage/main.o
>   ../../../../Build/Debug/writemessage/moc_messagesender.o
>   -F/Users/xxxxxxx/NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib
>   -L/Users/xxxxxxx/NokiaQtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib
>   -F/Users/xxxxxxx/lib -L/Users/xxxxxxx/lib -framework Message
>   -F/Users/xxxxxxx/install/Library/Frameworks
>   -L/Users/xxxxxxx/install/Library/Frameworks
>   -framework QtMobilitySimulator -framework QtMessaging -framework QtGui
>   -L/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib -F/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib -framework QtNetwork -framework QtCore  ld: warning: directory
>   '/Users/xxxxxxx/install/Library/Frameworks'
>   following -L not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib'
>   following -L not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Users/xxxxxxx/install/Library/Frameworks'
>   following -F not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib'
>   following -F not found  ld: framework
>   not found QtMobilitySimulator 
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
>   ld: warning: directory
>   '/Users/xxxxxxx/install/Library/Frameworks'
>   following -L not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib'
>   following -L not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Users/xxxxxxx/install/Library/Frameworks'
>   following -F not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib'
>   following -F not found  ld: framework
>   not found QtMobilitySimulator 
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
>   ld: warning: directory
>   '/Users/xxxxxxx/install/Library/Frameworks'
>   following -L not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib'
>   following -L not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Users/xxxxxxx/install/Library/Frameworks'
>   following -F not found  ld: warning:
>   directory
>   '/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib'
>   following -F not found  ld: framework
>   not found QtMobilitySimulator 
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
>   lipo: can't open input file:
>   /var/folders/CP/CP8sR5YZGx0b2xA2gYP5YE+++TI/-Tmp-//ccoxcfz2.out
>   (No such file or directory)  make: ***
>   [writemessage.app/Contents/MacOS/writemessage]
>   Error 1  make: Leaving directory`
>   /Users/xxxxxxx/Qt/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.1.0-beta2/examples/writemessage-build-simulator'
>   The process "/usr/bin/make" exited
>   with code %2. Error while building
>   project writemessage (target: Qt
>   Simulator) When executing build step
>   'Make'

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .pro file:

```
macx { 
    LIBS += -framework Message
}
```

And include headers this way:

```
#include <Message/MessageExport.h>
```

This should work with Qt 4.7.

Comment: Hi stephen, is there any procedure to install the open source frameworks that i ma using. I tried what ever you have specified, but getting errors. I have listed them in the question.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I got this error:                                       ":: warning: directory '/Installer/______BUILD______PADDED______/ndk/Simulator/Qt/gcc/lib' following -L not found" after using the statement s you have provided. I guess the problem is with Messaging framework installation in my Mac. Can you tell me the procedure to do it?

Comment: Raised a bug with Nokia. Updated in the Question. Have a look at it.

Comment: I think I may have mistaken what "Messaging framework" is in your question. I thought it was the Message framework in OS X. Is it some 3rd party lib? The term framework thew me off. :)

Comment: Just read your new edit. Ya. I was wrong. My answer was for using OS X system frameworks. Sorry for that.